# how to move a foreign key from one model to another without breaking data in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

previous model hierarchy:

```
class A(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
B = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
C = models.ForeignKey(C, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

new model hierarchy:

```
class A(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
B = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
C = models.ForeignKey(C, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class B(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Just moving the foreign key from model B to Model A

I have already made the change to the model and adjusted all the relevant queries in my django app, but I have no strategy right now as far as how to deploy these changes without breaking data, let alone a rollback plan..

Can these changes be made with migrations alone, or will I be forced to touch sql?

UPDATED:

Is there any risk to running something something like this as part of a migration?

```
def populate_a(apps, schema_editor):
    A = apps.get_model('app', 'a')

    for record in A.objects.all():        
        record.c = record.b.c
        j.save()
```

Comment: One way of doing this would be three migrations: first a schema migration to add the fk to A, then a data migration to move the appropriate data from each B record to the respective A record, and a final schema migration to remove the fk on B.

Comment: I just updated my post with a potential solution, can I just run the script above to populate the foreign keys in A?  Then maybe run another script to remove the 'C' foreign key from model 'B' ?